# Limits in Complex sequences

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Proof that $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to \infty}\dfrac{\log z}{\sqrt[n]{z}}=0$, in Complex numbers.
I have the following question. Can I tell that if the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\to +\infty}\dfrac{\log |z|}{\sqrt[n]{|z|}}=0$, then our previous limit goes to $0$, as z tends to $\infty$? I think that this is true if our first limit exist. I should proof that with the definition. Any ideas? (Please, don't try to comput the limit with L'Hopital rule because I am trying to understand the definition). Thanks

Comment: What is $\log z$? And what is $\sqrt[n]z$?

Comment: While $\lvert\sqrt[n]{z}\rvert=\sqrt[n]{\lvert z\rvert}$ by all means, it is entirely possible for $\lvert \log z\rvert$ to be, for most values of $z$, larger than $\log\lvert z\rvert$.

Comment: $\log z=ln|z|+i Arg(z)$ and $\sqrt[n]{z}=|z|^{1/n} e^{i Arg(z)/n}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Concequently, the first I wrote was wrong in some cases, because I cannot bound the $\lvert \log z\rvert$ by $\log\lvert z\rvert$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider the following limit instead.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z \to \infty} \left| \frac{\log z}{\sqrt[n]{z}} \right| & = \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{|\log z|}{|\sqrt[n]{z}|} \\
& = \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{|\ln |z| + i \operatorname{Arg} (z)|}{| |z|^{1/n} e^{i \operatorname{Arg} (z)/n} |} \\
& = \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{|\ln |z| + i \operatorname{Arg} (z)|}{|z|^{1/n}}  \\
& \leq \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{|\ln |z|| + |i \operatorname{Arg} (z)|}{|z|^{1/n}} &\text{(By triangle inequality)} \\
& = \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{\ln |z|}{|z|^{1/n}} + \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{|\operatorname{Arg} (z)|}{|z|^{1/n}}
\end{align*}
The first limit can be reduced to the form
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^{1/n}} $$
where $x$ is real. So the limit can be computed to be 0 by using techniques in real analysis. For the second limit, notice that
$$ \frac{|\operatorname{Arg} (z)|}{|z|^{1/n}} \leq \frac{\pi}{|z|^{1/n}} \to 0 \text{ as } z \to \infty $$
So the limit is 0 by squeeze theorem. Altogether, we have shown
$$  \lim_{z \to \infty}  \frac{\log z}{\sqrt[n]{z}} \leq \lim_{z \to \infty} \left| \frac{\log z}{\sqrt[n]{z}} \right| \leq \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{\ln |z|}{|z|^{1/n}} + \lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{|\operatorname{Arg} (z)|}{|z|^{1/n}} = 0 + 0 = 0. $$
Therefore the original limit is also 0 by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much it's clear. Maybe, at the point you write that $|Arg(z)|\leq \pi /2$ you mean $\leq \pi$, or anyway we can tell $Arg(z)$ is bounded, and we know that the limit of  fg, so that f goes to 0 and g is bounded, is $0$.

Comment: Oh yes, that’s a typo. I will change it later.